# How to access the field value from rest output using python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython

Here is my structure:

```
[
            {
                "name": "ga0",
                "fullName": "gac0",
                "key": "office"
                "id" : "Apps/tex3435",
                "value" : "test2"
            },
            {
                "name": "gasec1",
                "fullName": "gasec1",
                "key": "PRINCIPAL"
                "id" : "Apps/tex3433",
                "value" : "test"
            }
]
```

I want to grab the id of key `PRINCIPAL`.

Comment: You have a list consisting of two elements, which are dictionaries, and you want to access the value of `key` of the second dictionary. How would you do it?

Comment: Do you want to get the value of whatever the key titled "key" is pointing at? Because your question makes it seem like PRINCIPAL is meant to be the key, but is represented as a value.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. The solution that I posted gives you the key which are corresponding value - PRINCIPAL. But now you want "id" where the key is principal, doesn't make sense because the key for principal is "Key"

Comment: here is my question I want to grab the id of key value PRINCIPAL.  All i want is get this value "Apps/tex3433" which is not unique all the time. only thing which is unique is "key": "PRINCIPAL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution returns a list `r` of entries in `l` which have `key = PRINCIPAL`.

```py
l = [
            {
                "name": "ga0",
                "fullName": "gac0",
                "key": "office",
                "id" : "Apps/tex3435",
                "value" : "test2"
            },
            {
                "name": "gasec1",
                "fullName": "gasec1",
                "key": "PRINCIPAL",
                "id" : "Apps/tex3433",
                "value" : "test"
            }
]

r = filter(lambda k: k['key']=="PRINCIPAL", l)
print(r[0]['id'])
```

Comment: this code as is doesn't actually execute, throws a TypeError because filter objects aren't subscriptable.

Comment: It will throw an error in Python3 because `r` will be a filter object which is not subscriptable. You can make it work in Python3 by changing it to `list(filter(...))`. It should work fine in Python2.7 as is.

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop to get key for the value > "PRINCIPAL":

```
d = [
{
"name": "ga0",
"fullName": "gac0",
"key": "office",
"id" : "Apps/tex3435",
"value" : "test2"
},   
{
"name": "gasec1",
"fullName": "gasec1",
"key": "PRINCIPAL",
"id" : "Apps/tex3433",
"value" : "test"
}]

for x in d:

    # x is a dictionary, so we now iterate over its key - value pair
    # Use x.iteritems() for Python 2

    for key, values in x.items():
        if values == 'PRINCIPAL':
            print(key)

# Using list comprehension
print([i for x in d for i, j in zip(x.keys(), x.values()) if j == 'PRINCIPAL'])
```

Comment: So i want to access the id field value of the key principal , How do we do that ?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I want to parse "id" : "Apps/tex3433" from that second element where key is PRINCIPAL.

Comment: PRINCIPAL is not a key. It's a value in the dictionary

Comment: correct, so i want to parse "id" : "Apps/tex3433" for that key, if you see there are multiple id values, actual output has 100 elements like these, so it will be 100 id values, but i want to parse the id value of element key which has value PRINCIPAL.  Basically i want to parse one id value out of 100 and PRINCIPAL is the unique key for that